# Why does ReportLab KeepInFrame shrink text too much?

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using ReportLab to fill out a pre-existing form, so I need text to appear in specific places on the document. To facilitate this I wrote a this little function:

```
def drawFrame(can, text, x, y, w, h, style):
  p = Paragraph(text,style)
  f = KeepInFrame(w,h,[p],mode='shrink', vAlign='MIDDLE', hAlign='LEFT')
  f.wrapOn(can,w,h)
  f.drawOn(can,x,y)
```

It undeniably puts text in the appropriate boxes. The problem is that if the text is even slightly too large for the box it shrinks it to something like half size, making it nearly unreadable. Is there a simple way make it shrink the text slightly?

I tried using drawString rather than the flowable based function, but I couldn't get that to scale or wrap text at all. I played with the alignment and fakeWidth parameters, but they seemed to have no affect on the scaling. Manually using a smaller font by changing the style avoids the issue, but makes everything smaller, including things that don't need to be.